Howto determine the value of bound input parameters before/after SQLExecDirect or SQLExecute
In order trace the SQL statements executed by my program, I need to determine the type and memory locations of the input parameters (SQLBindParameter) before/after calling SQLExecDirect or SQLExecute. Is are a way to do this?
